# Many of my Android users cannot login with Facebook

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

I have an android application, and we are using the new Facebook SDK (version 3.0.1). Many of my users cannot get in and login with Facebook. After clicking on the Facebook login button, it opens the Facebook `LoginActivity` and stays there for ever.

---

```
            /**My Activity **/
            public class RegisterActivity extends FragmentActivity{

            @Override
                public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        
                    setContentView(R.layout.register);

                    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
                        // Add the fragment on initial activity setup
                        mainFragment = new RegistrationFragment();
                        getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .add(android.R.id.content, mainFragment)
                        .commit();
                    } else {
                        // Or set the fragment from restored state info
                        mainFragment = (RegistrationFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                                .findFragmentById(android.R.id.content);
                    }
            ...
            }

                    public void onStart() {

                    mainFragment.initialize(this,R.layout.register,false);
                    super.onStart();

                }
                ...
            }
            /**My Fragment **/
            public class RegistrationFragment extends Fragment{
            @Override
                public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), callback);
                    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                }
                private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {


                    if(state == SessionState.OPENING){

                        registrationManager.updateState(FlurryAccess.REGISTRATION_FACEBOOK_LOGIN_START,flurryParams);
                        registrationManager.startLogin();
                    }
                    else if (state.isOpened()) {

                        registrationManager.updateState(FlurryAccess.REGISTRATION_FACEBOOK_LOGIN_LOGGED_IN,flurryParams);

                        if(!sentRequest){
                            sentRequest = true;
                            makeMeRequest(session);
                        }

                    } else if (state.isClosed()) {

                    }
                }
                private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
                        onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
                    }
                };
                    @Override
                public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
                    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

                    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                }

        @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
            ViewGroup container, 
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final View view = inflater.inflate(layoutRes, container, false);

        LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.facebook_login);


        authButton.setFragment(this);
...
}
                     ...
            }
```

Comment: Hi Carlos, I added the code to the question. Thanks

Comment: Is the LoginButton inside your RegistrationFragment? If so, you need to get the LoginButton and call setFragment(this) on it.

Comment: Hi, Yes Know I did this.